# Correlation values aren't significant but the coefficients of regression are

Tags: correlation, robust

I ran a regression model between X and y. I used robust regression. The results are significant, but when I ran a Pearson correlation I found that the correlation values aren't significant. I don't understand how this can happen.

Comment: Try with ordinary least squares and check if you get the same p values as with Pearson correlation (as expected). Robust regression leads to different results than OLS, so there is no reason to expect its results to correspond.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding a bit on @Michael 's comment:

With a single independent variable you ought to get the same p-value from an OLS regression and a correlation and, if the assumptions of OLS are met, this is fine:

```
set.seed(1234)  #Set seed for replicabiity
x1 <- rnorm(100, 10, 1) #Random normal, mean 10, sd 1
y1 <- 10 + 3*x1  + rnorm(100, 0, 20) #The true model

m1 <- lm(y1~x1) 
summary(m1)  #p = 0.24
cor.test(x1,y1) #p = 0.24

plot(x1,y)
```

However, since you are using robust regression, I am guessing that the assumptions are *not* met.  Perhaps you have a few outliers.

```
x2 <- c(rnorm(95, 10, 1), rnorm(5,100,10)) #5 outliers
y2 <- 10 + 3*x2  + rnorm(100, 0, 20) #The true model
m2 <- lm(y~x2) 
summary(m2)  #p = 0.67, parameter estimate = -0.04
cor.test(x2,y) #p = 0.67, cor = -0.04

plot(x2,y)

require(MASS)
m3 <- rlm(y2~x2)
summary(m3) #parameter estimate = 3.23, p value not given but t = 28.4
```

Correlation still matches OLS, but neither is appropriate.

Comment: thanks alot ,peter , actually i have 7 Independence variables

Comment: If you have more than one independent variable then the correlation (which is bivariate) need not be similar to the regression results (which control for other variables).